# How to delete download image data in cache.db in device(iphone and ipad)

Tags: ios

i am new to iOS
In my project i am display images in tableview by lazy loading.But all download images url are stored in cache.db.So,the memory will be low when i am doing this process continuously 
please tell me how to manage memory here

Comment: Go with this doc you will get your answer I hope. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not experienced about caching, but I think you can disable or limit caching. To disable caching you can use the following code

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
[sharedCache release];
```

Take a look at this blog entry about cache limiting
http://twobitlabs.com/2012/01/ios-ipad-iphone-nsurlcache-uiwebview-memory-utilization/

Hope it helps